# Why are small weights helpful in Deep Neural Networks(Regularisation)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have been studying Neural Networks for long time and I am actually stuck at this topic called regularisation. I Learned L1, L2 regularisation techniques and main aim of that techniques is to keep the weights as small as possible. But I still didn't get why is that useful. I was actually following this book- http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful not from a theoretical aspect but from a practical one.

Weights of a neural net are usually stored as 16 or 32-bit floating point numbers. For deep neural networks, if you don't add a regularization term to the backpropagation, their weights will increase past what the floats can represent well (to infinity) or become so small that they're all represented as zeros, and the neural net will no longer function.

This is something called the vanishing or exploding gradient problem. Adding a sum of the weights to the cost function allows us to keep the weights practical while also optimizing the loss function.

Comment: Thanks my doubt was clarified but wont penalizing large weights make our network to have weights near to 0 and eventually approach 0. Wont that be a problem.